# Как выполнить strip('\') в Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

У меня есть путь к файлу:

```
path = "C:\Users\Рэм\Desktop\Учёба в универе\Курсовая ТПР\CHRIS-MGEX_IC1"
```

Мне нужно разбить всю строку по '\'.
Пишу

```
a =  path.strip('\')
```

Однако данный трюк не срабатывает.
Как разбить строку по \?

Comment: `path.split('\\')` ?

Comment: Да, сработало, спасибо!

Comment: strip() **удаляет** перечисленные символы **в начале** и **в конце** строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MaxU ответил на мой вопрос:

```
path.split('\\')
```